# How to measure exact execution time for a process/method that gets frequently interrupted?

Tags: java, timing

Currently this is how I get time elapsed for a process to get completed.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
process();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long duration = stop - start;
System.out.println(duration);
```

The problem I am facing currently is the `process()` gets interrupted(paused) by my pc's hibernation whenever there's no power(My work environment is outside so I have to be on battery) so that it can continue whenever I restart the pc when plugged. I am fully aware I would get a wrong duration if for example I am not able to restart for about 2hrs since the process got paused(during hibernation) as this would mean the extra 2hrs will be accounted for by the CPU clock via the CMOS battery backup whenever the line

```
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

is reached. How would it be possible to get the exact duration irrespective of the process being paused severally.

Comment: Sounds a bit odd that you're timing a process, and you'd let your computer sleep in between. To get what you want would probably require native code, making the solution a lot more complex than your problem. If you're timing an operation, don't let your computer sleep. It's simple as that.

Comment: As i understand, there is a similar ticket created on JDK see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146730

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni doesn't look to be related, since it's about specific native timing on the Windows platform. The question is more about "how to measure wall clock time minus time spent in hibernation".

Comment: @Kayaman the `process()` is a time consuming one, it's not something that can be completed in a day and power stability at my work environment  isn't constant at the moment. specifically it's a process with a loop from 0 to a BigInteger number sorta

Comment: You could rent a cheap server from amazon and run your code there for as long as you like. That would be the most straight-forward solution. If you don't have reliable power / network, you're not going to be a very efficient developer, especially if you need to use tricks to keep on developing. But I'll give you something...

Comment: This might sound a bit noob but what about using the Date class to your advantage? I mean, you can get the current time before and after a process and calculate the difference. The only downside to this (that I can think of) is the minute time-lag that might occur while trying to get the current time.

Answer (score 1):

So your question is "how much wall clock time was taken by the process, without time spent in hibernation". Well, wall clock time is easy to get, but you don't really have a chance to know whether hibernation happened or not.

*However...*

If your process is a set of discrete steps, you could do something like the following

```
List<Duration> durations = new ArrayList<>();
for(Step step : steps) {
    Instant stepStart = Instant.now();
    process(step);
    durations.add(Duration.between(stepStart, Instant.now()));
}

long totalMillis = durations.stream()
    .mapToLong(Duration::toMillis)
    .filter(ms -> ms < 1000)   // Cut off limit, to disregard hibernate steps
    .sum();
```

This times each step separately, and if the time for a step takes more than 1 second, it's not taken into account in the total. You could also use an "average" time for those steps, so the end result would be a bit more realistic (of course this depends on the number of steps, the assumed runtime of a single step, etc.).

This only works if there is a good limit to what is "too much" time, and it provides a less accurate result. If you're doing something with `BigInteger`, it's likely that steps with larger values take more time, so a single cutoff value would not work (although you could consider some kind of dynamic cutoff value, based on the input).

Cheapest, easiest and best solution: run the code on a server.